# Pad a specific column with escape characters in Bash

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a file consisting of rows of data, where columns are specified by a given delimiter.

e.g.

```
20170202,ABC,USD,USD,100,20170202
20170202,ABC,GBP,USD,200,20170202
20170201,ABC,NOK,USD,300,20170204
20170131,ABC,DKK,USD,400,20170202
```

I would like a way to print the rows of this file where, for instance, column 1 is 20170202 AND column 4 is USD. At the same time, I want to surround those columns in the printed output with escape characters, to highlight them to the user.

So in the example above, only rows 1 and 2 should be printed, and:

- column 1 (but NOT column 6) should be highlighted
- column 4 (but NOT column 3) should be highlighted

Currently I have a chained grep for each argument passed.

e.g.

```
cat myfile.txt | grep -w "20170202" | grep -w "USD"
```

This is then piped to a sed statement which pads 20170202 and USD with the escape characters to colour the output.

However, in the example above this would fail for row 4, as it will be erroneously output, with column 4 and column 6 highlighted. It also fails for row 1, for which columns 1, 3, 4 and 6 will be highlighted (when I only want 1 and 4).

Can anyone advise on how to do this for an arbitrary selection of columns?

Including awk as I imagine the solution to this might involve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In <kbd>awk</kbd> you can replace fields as colored fields. Below script should
do the job

```
# cat 42000109
1. 20170202,ABC,USD,USD,100,20170202
2. 20170202,ABC,GBP,USD,200,20170202
3. 20170201,ABC,NOK,USD,300,20170204
4. 20170131,ABC,DKK,USD,400,20170202

# awk -v FS=" |," '$2=="20170202" && $4=="USD"{$2="\033[1;31m"$2"\033[1;39m";$4="\033[1;31m"$4"\033[1;39m";print}' 42000109

1. 20170202 ABC USD USD 100 20170202
#fields 2 and 4 will be highlighted
```

For more tips on bash colors, check [[ this ]](http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting) link.

**Edit**

If the numbers in the beginning doesn't exist then below stuff should do

```
# awk -v FS=',' -v OFS=',' '$1=="20170202" && $4=="USD"{$1="\033[1;31m"$1"\033[1;39m";$4="\033[1;31m"$4"\033[1;39m";print}' 42000109
20170202,ABC,USD,USD,100,20170202
20170202,ABC,GBP,USD,200,20170202
# #fields 1 and 4 will be highlighted
```

Comment: Sorry, the 1. 2. 3. 4. at the beginning of each row was just to clarify. Those don't exist in the actual file. How does your answer change, given this?

Comment: Thank you for the assistance

Comment: You can use `-F,` to set `FS`, rather than `-v FS=,`

Answer (score 1):

Consider building a map of the colors you want first and then using it, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    n = split("\
        red     31 \
        green   32 \
        reset   39 \
            ", tmpA)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i+=2) {
        colors[tmpA[i]] = ("\033[1;" tmpA[i+1] "m")
    }
    FS=OFS=","
}

function color(field,clr) {
    $field = (colors[clr] $field colors["reset"])
}

($1=="20170202") && ($4=="USD") {
    color(1,"red")
    color(4,"green")
}

{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file | cat -v
^[[1;31m20170202^[[1;39m,ABC,USD,^[[1;32mUSD^[[1;39m,100,20170202
^[[1;31m20170202^[[1;39m,ABC,GBP,^[[1;32mUSD^[[1;39m,200,20170202
20170201,ABC,NOK,USD,300,20170204
20170131,ABC,DKK,USD,400,20170202
```

Comment: This is hugely over-engineered for what I've asked for. sjsam's answer was sufficient, and I believe already marked as correct when this was posted. Thanks anyway (had wrong user, so recommented)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with providing a different answer after one is marked as correct. The accepted answer is sometimes simply wrong (not in this case) and often not the best one. This forum is for people to search for answers to questions, not to provide just you with the answer to your specific question, so while you may find this to be over-engineered for your specific example it provides the general solution to the general problem you described and bear in mind most people minimize their real problem when posting a question so a general solution is often preferable to a  minimal solution.

Comment: `^1` Nice one, well reply too

Answer (score 0):

using a <kbd>sed</kbd> (a bit hard to read with all those `\`)

```
sed -e '/^\(20170202\)\(,\([^,]*,\)\{3\}\)\(USD\)\(,.*\)/!d' -e 's//\\\1\\\2\\\4\\\5/' YourFile

# OR into a more generic form
sed -e '/^\('${YourDate}'\)\(,\([^,]*,\)\{3\}\)\('${YourCurrency}'\)\(,.*\)/!d' -e 's//\\\1\\\2\\\4\\\5/' YourFile
```

<kbd>awk</kbd> version

```
awk '$1=="20170202"&&$4=="USD"{$1="\\"$1"\\";$4="\\"$4"\\";print}' FS=',' OFS=',' YourFile
```

same, more generic, with comment (using variable for batching)

```
awk -v MyDate="{YourDate}" -v MyCur="${YourCurrency} '
   # Parameter assign some variable with external value of script

   # if first field (col) = the date AND 4th field = Currency
   $1 == MyDate && $4 == MyCur {
      # replace field 1 by itself surrounded by escape char
      $1 = "\\" $1 "\\"
      # same for field 4
      $4 = "\\" $4 "\\"

      # Print line (with new content)
      # default output is modified by OFS value adapted (default is space separator between field and set to , in this script)
      print 
      }
   # assign 2 varible (FS and OFS for field separator as input and output)
   # before reading first availble file (YourFile)
   ' FS=',' OFS=',' YourFile
```

Answer (score -2):

```
cat text file| awk -F "," '$1 ~ /20170202/ && $3 == "USD"  { print }'
```

`awk` takes in the delimiter comma "," for the present file and splits them which can be accessed through $1, $2, $3 and so on. So we can try to see if the match is true for $1 and $3 as required. $1 match is done through regex match which is done through the operator `~` and the regex string is kept with forward slashes `/`.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.